# In react-redux, can any components request for current state from the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Say for example, a component needs to access a current state, can it at anytime directly request for the current state from the store? Meaning it's a two-way between the store and any components? I am a bit lost cause in a data-flow map, I always see only one arrow from store to components.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The overarching paradigm in React and redux/flux is a one way data flow. Components never "ask" for anything from the store, but rather, any time the store changes, all the components get notified of the new data. If the data requires a component to change, React takes care of doing that smartly.

So unlike in something like jQuery where you say "when this value changes, find this element and change it", in React you say "this is what my element should look like at any given moment" and React does the changing.

As a developer you now no longer have to think about when and how components change, you just tell them what they should look like, and they'll change when they need to based on the data they're given.

Comment: I understand how the store updates the components whenever there's change. But my question is, in the case of no change and some components just need to access the current state for usage, can it request for it from the store?

Comment: If the component will need access to a piece of state, that state should be passed down as a prop into the component and then that component will constantly have access to it, without having to ask. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So technically prop is doing the requesting for a piece of state from the store, correct?

Comment: Pretty much. I wouldn't think of it as requesting because that's sort of backwards, but yes, adding a prop on a component grants that component perpetual access to that prop.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! One more quick question, is it a proper react-redux design for children components to get the updated state directly from the store? Or should it be passed down from top to bottom.

Comment: It's up to you how many components you connect, and where they live in your UI hierarchy.  Find a good balance that works for you.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-multiple-components.

Comment: @dannyid Noted. Thank you so much for all your help! Definitely learned a handful!

Comment: @dannyid One more quickie if you don't mind! Just came up. Is it possible to pass two slices of state into one reducer?

Comment: @JoKo, I'm not sure what you mean. Each reducer is taking care of one piece of state. If you have two pieces of state that need to be changed by an action, you'll want more than one reducer listening for that action. Hope I understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your one-way data flow arrows are correct.

At any time, any React component, or any other type of component type can request the current state of the application using `store.getState()`.  (http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html).

This is not two way, because **you cannot mutate the store data directly**. You dispatch actions that are handled by reducers which percolate updates through the state tree.

The `@component` decorator, and the `Provider` component in the `react-redux` project are React-specific utilities that subscribe to store state-change events, and triggers component re-renders.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that one. One quick question, is it a proper react-redux design for children components to get the updated state directly from the store? Or should it be passed down from top to bottom, layer by layer.

Comment: It's totally fine for children to get their data from the store. Some people prefer to architect their applications so that there are "containers" vs "simple components". Simple components are rendered based purely on their props, which include data and callbacks, and may be re-used in different contexts. "Containers" interact with your Redux state and inject that state into simple components.

Comment: So in the case where the children components gets current or updated state directly from the store, it wouldn't be passing down their data props, correct? And could be for callbacks as well, if children components get them directly from the store? Or must the callbacks always be passed down by one smart component?

Comment: And as in "containers" are you referring to smart components? Is having only one smart component typically the way to go?

Comment: Yes, "containers" and "smart components" are the same thing. In my apps, I tend to use a handful of smart components on a page that inject data into simpler, functional leaf nodes. Exactly how you inject data into your components is kind of up to you. Some people like leaf components to hit the data store, some don't. Don't get too caught up in the idea of the "correct way" of architecting this. Try out a couple of different approaches and feel out what you like better.

Comment: Noted. Thank you so much for all your help! Definitely learned a handful!

Comment: One more quickie if you don't mind! Just came up. Is it possible to pass two slices of state into one reducer?

Comment: Not really; if you want a reducer to manage a sub-tree of state, that's fine, but if you want to manage different, unrelated parts of the state tree, it's not possible.

Comment: If you need pieces of data that are derivative of what's in the state tree, look at the reselect library.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `react-redux` bindings, there is a neater, less costly way than `store.getState()`: [the `connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

From the docs, `Connect` returns

> a React component class that injects state and action creators into your component according to the specified options.

Say, for instance, you want to grab your current user from `state` from store in your `Login` component, you could do something like this (no action creators here, just state):

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    user: state.user
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
   actions: bindActionCreators(loginActions, dispatch)
 };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Auth);
```

In order to allow `connect` to inject state in your props you must pass `mapStateToProps` to it. If you don't give it any argument it only inject `dispatch` by default.

This method goes very well with the smart(or containers)/dumb( or presentational) components pattern. You would use `connect` in your stateful containers, leaving the presentational components stateless.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation. If you don't mind, could you show an example with a action creators injected component?

Comment: Sure. You'd use the `mapDispatchToProps` to pass the actions you need. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! What do you think about even dumb components using connect to get state directly from the store? How dumb components getting action creator directly from the store? Is it the proper way to handle redux?

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please read this https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.y60cggm3b; but no, it wouldn't be a great idea to connect a dumb component to store. I mean you _can_ do it, but it's not how it is intended.

Comment: Noted. Thank you so much for all your help! Definitely learned a handful!

Comment: One more quickie if you don't mind! Just came up. Is it possible to pass two slices of state into one reducer?

Comment: That's probably worth a new question :)